# Regex - Finding alphanumeric inbetween {{ and }}

Tags: regex

I want to find all alphanumeric characters between `{{` and `}}` in a text.
Eg. if the text contain the substring `{{foo}}` I want to find `foo`.
If it contains `{{#foo}}` I want to find foo not `#foo`.

I have tried the following pattern `(?<=\\{\\{)(.*?)(?=\\}\\})`, but it always returns `#` in the second example above.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What if it contains `{{f#oo}}`?

Comment: Fyi, please use backticks instead of asterisks to enclose code and code-like text. Additionally it is usually a good idea to mention the regex engine you are using.

Comment: dasblinkenlight: That's a good point. If the string is `f#oo` I want `foo` back. I.e. I want to ignore non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: ThiefMaster: Thanks for the tip. I'm using the engine in .net.

Comment: @GustavGahm My solution does not accept `f#oo` the way that you want. I edited my answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(?<=\{\{[^A-Za-z0-9]*)([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?=.*\}\})
```

This expression lets you skip non-alphanumeric characters after `{{` and before the first alphanumeric character, if any. It also lets you have non-alphanumerics preceding the closing `}}`.

**EDIT**

In response to your comment about `f#oo`: as far as I know, you cannot "glue together" multiple non-contiguous matched groups. The easiest solution is to use another regexp in your C# hosting program:

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"\W"); // Any non-word character
var result = rgx.Replace("f#oo$bar", ""); // Returns "foobar"
```

You would need to go back to your original regexp, because the one from the answer matches only the first contiguous block of alphanumerics.